# Java 8 Stream read file for every 100 lines

Tags: lambda, java-8, stream

Let's say I have a huge file and I would like to read 100 every lines and do one operation. (I want to combine 100 lines and send a rest request)

In Java 7, I would do something like below.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

    String line;
    int count = 0;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();       
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(line);
        count++;
        if (count % 100 == 0) {
            //do the operation on list
            list = new ArrayList();
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there something we can leverage Java 8 Stream here?
I know we can do something like this but it operates on each line instead of 100 lines. So I think foreach is not the option here.

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
    stream.forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you can send a rest request per 100 lines in java-8 stream in parallel.

Comment: @Eugene why did you said the `skip` operation is not recommend?

Comment: @Eugene No. you need first calculate all lines, that is simple and fast. and put the time-consuming operation in parallel streams .

Comment: I don't want to load everything into list(memory) and then process all. The file will be over 100GB so I am looking for some lazy operation or something like read 100 lines from file and do the operation and continue doing the same...

Comment: @holi-java then you would be hitting the memory issue... that the OP makes clear he does not wants to

Comment: I would do it with a custom collector. Once 100 lines are read, I'd invoke a consumer to send those 100 lines in a request. But there should be better ways to do it, I think, maybe partitioning the stream with a spliterator...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like the approach above you can simply using the second approach, but you can't create partial streams in parallel since you must read the `lines` sequentially. for example:

```
split(Paths.get("file"), 100).forEach(this::sendRequest);

void sendRequest(List<String> each) {
  // then you must send the rest request in parallel here
}
```

---

```
Stream<List<String>> split(Path path, int limit) throws IOException {
    // skip the remaining lines if its size < limit
    return split(Files.lines(path), limit, true);
}

<T> Stream<List<T>> split(Stream<T> source,
                          int limit, boolean skipRemainingElements) {

    //variables just for printing purpose
    Spliterator<T> it = source.spliterator();
    long size = it.estimateSize();
    int c = it.characteristics();// characteristics

    return stream(new AbstractSpliterator<List<T>>(size, c) {
        private int thresholds = skipRemainingElements ? limit : 1;

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super List<T>> action) {
            List<T> each = new ArrayList<>(limit);

            while (each.size() < limit && it.tryAdvance(each::add)) ;

            if (each.size() < thresholds) return false;

            action.accept(each);
            return true;
        }

    }, false).onClose(source::close);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split the stream by using [Stream#skip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-) and [Stream#limit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-), and then send a rest request per 100 lines in parallel. for example:

```
split(Paths.get("file"), 100).parallel().forEach(this::sendRequest);
```

---

```
Stream<Stream<String>> split(Path path, int limit) throws IOException {
    return LongStream.of(0, lines(path) / limit).parallel()
            .map(it -> it * limit)
            .mapToObj(offset -> {
                try {
                    return Files.lines(path).skip(offset).limit(limit);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RejectedExecutionException(e);
                }
            });
}

long lines(Path path) throws IOException {
    try (LineNumberReader in = open(path)) {
        return in.getLineNumber();
    }
}

LineNumberReader open(Path path) throws IOException {
    return new LineNumberReader(newBufferedReader(path));
}

void sendRequest(Stream<String> each) {
    try (BufferedWriter out = null) {// todo: create the output writer
        each.forEach(line -> {
            try {
                out.write(line);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // todo: handle error
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //todo: handle error
    }
}
```

**IF** you want higher performance, you must implements your own algorithm in `split` & `lines` method. and Note `LineNumberReader#getLineNumber` is an `int` rather than an `long`. for calculate lines I think there are many opensource projects that can be calculates the total lines number in parallel.

**AND** this just an skeleton, if you want the highest performance. first, you need indexing the line information, e.g:(`totalLines` and `offset`) in parallel (*the algorithm like as merge sort*)  into memory or disk if needed. then you can using `RandomeAccessFile` to jump to the `offset` quickly.

### The Indexed Line Information File Format like as below

```
total_lines|ofsset1|offset2|...|offsetN
```

**Note**: there is no separator `|` in the Line Information File. and each value you must using `DataOutputStream#writeLong` to write as a `long`, because write the Line Information File in this format you can calculate the position of `offsetN` by bytes, e.g: `8*M; M=(1..N)`, then you can obtain the `offsetN` by read 8 bytes from the `offsetN`.

Indeed, the index file should be created when the huge file (*if the file is too huge, it need to split too*) was created, then it can saving lost of your time for using as further.

Comment: But this creates a new stream for every new page! It reads the file many, many times, creating lots of access to disk, file handles and other OS resources, etc. Have you tested it?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes, the algorithm is `N+1` but it can create partial streams & send requests in parallel.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner you can control the fork join pool thread size resonably and for the requests it is just reading so I think there is no problem, sir.